# Flutter Jitsi Meet Dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, jitsi-meet

Does the jitsi_meet and jitsi_meet_wrapper package in flutter have the same functions as jitsi_meet has been discontinued and replaced by jitsi_meet_wrapper

I need to know if i can still use jitsi_meet package functionalities after using jitsi_meet_wrapper

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.